# Limit logins to Drupal to specific IP block

Tags: security, configuration, drupal

I'd like to allow anonymous from anywhere, while limiting authenticated to one or few IP blocks.

Can this be done in drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "access rules" in your control panel: admin/user/rules

Adding a rule and selecting "host" you can allow or deny access by a specified IP Address (tipically allow your range then deny everything else, no implicit deny here.) 
Unfortunatly this is a "global option" (not user or group based) so act carefully you can shut yourself out from your own site.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely a hack, but you could add something like the following in the login module/script (or include it) thus preventing those not in the IP range from accessing the login module:

```
<?php

$allowed_ips = array('1.2.3.4','5.6.7.8');
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(!in_array($client_ip,$allowed_ips)) {
    die('authentication denied'); // or you could redirect to a 403 or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a feature request pending, however, a developer has already put together some code which may work: [Support for role based IP restriction](http://drupal.org/node/237614)